# How can I validate XML embedded in JSON using Citrus framework?

Tags: java, json, xml, citrus-framework

In my Citrus test, I’m trying to validate an XML message that is embedded in a JSON document (the output of WireMock). The XML text needs to be parsed because it contains timestamps I want to ignore. The XML part of the JSON message looks like this:

```
"requests": [
{
    "id": "52844d5a-59de-4288-8000-7f48fcda41e5",
    "request": {
        "body": "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"> [content omitted] </soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>",
}
]
```

This is my Java test code:

```
http()
    .client(wiremockClient)
    .receive()
    .response(HttpStatus.OK)
    .messageType(MessageType.JSON)
    .extractFromPayload("$.requests[0].request.body", "body")
    .payload(new ClassPathResource("output/esb/add_conf_to_cart/response2.xml"))
;
```

where respon2.xml contains the XML text only (the contents of "body" in the JSON message shown above), and the error I’m getting from Citrus is

```
com.consol.citrus.exceptions.CitrusRuntimeException: Failed to parse JSON text
…
Caused by: net.minidev.json.parser.ParseException: Unexpected token <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=
```

So, how can I validate XML embedded in a JSON document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Clarifications

I have two remarks on your current solution:

1. `extractFromPayload(..)` extracts the `body` part of you JSON into a Citrus variables named `body`. This doesn't have anything to do with the `payload(..)` part. You just stored the JSON contents of `body`  into a Citrus variable `body`. You may or may not be aware of this
2. The `payload(..)` method will always validate the whole payload received, i.e., the whole JSON object.
3. If you only want to validate a part of the response, use [JSON Path validation](http://www.citrusframework.org/reference/html/index.html#validate-with-jsonpath):  `.validate("$.some.json.path", "someValue")`

### Solution

Citrus provides an internal method exactly for your use case, see documentation for [matchesXml()](http://www.citrusframework.org/reference/html/index.html#matcher-matches-xml).

#### Only validating the XML structure

This is the easiest solution:

```java
http()
    .client(wiremockClient)
    .receive()
    .response(HttpStatus.OK)
    .messageType(MessageType.JSON)
    .validate("$.requests[0].request.body", @matchesXml('citrus:readFile('classpath:output/esb/add_conf_to_cart/response2.xml')')@)
```

#### Validating the whole JSON response

In your case you simply match the whole JSON structure and put the method `@matchesXml('<some><validation_xml></some></validation_xml>')@` in the correct JSON entry:

```java
http()
.client(wiremockClient)
.receive()
.response(HttpStatus.OK)
.messageType(MessageType.JSON)
.payload("{\n"+
    "  \"requests\": {\n"+
    "    \"id\": \"52844d5a-59de-4288-8000-7f48fcda41e5\",\n"+
    "    \"request\": {\n"+
    "      \"body\": \"@matchesXml('<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\\\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\\\"> [content omitted] </soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>')@\"\n"+
    "    }\n"+
    "  }\n"+
    "}");
```

### Remarks

- The String put into `payload` must be valid JSON, i.e., quotes within a JSON value must be escaped.
- The quotes within a Java String must be escaped as well, hence we must write `\\\"`
- Citrus parses the `payload` String as JSON first and keeps it internally as JSON object where the escaped quotes are unescaped. It then passes this String to the validation function `matchesXml`.
- Your current example is not valid XML, since the tag `</soapenv:Body>` is never opened
- It is much easier to put payload requests into separate files, just be aware that the file still must be valid JSON, i.e., quotes escaped with one backslash like so `\"`
- You might want to read the XML content from a separate file. In this case you can use Citrus' [`citrus:readFile()`](http://www.citrusframework.org/reference/html/index.html#functions-read-file) function
- For the `payload`, you would still need to escape quotes within the XML. You could do so with [`citrus:translate()`](http://www.citrusframework.org/reference/html/index.html#functions-translate): `citrus:translate('citrus:readFile('classpath:some/path/to/response.xml')', '\"', '\\"')`
- The escaping is very tricky since we're dealing with quotes and backslashes which are special in Java, JSON and XML
- It should work as follows:

Create a file `response_validation.json`:

```json
{
  "requests": {
    "id": "52844d5a-59de-4288-8000-7f48fcda41e5",
    "request": {
      "body": "@matchesXml('${jsonEscapedXmlInput}')@"
    }
  }
}
```

In your test case create the Citrus variable `jsonEscapedXmlInput` which reads and escapes the XML file:

```
variable("jsonEscapedXml", "citrus:translate('citrus:readFile('classpath:output/esb/add_conf_to_cart/response2.xml')', '\\\"', '\\\\\"')")
```

Then use it

```
http()
    .client(wiremockClient)
    .receive()
    .response(HttpStatus.OK)
    .messageType(MessageType.JSON)
    .payload(new ClassPathResource("classpath:validation/response_validation.json"))
;
```

Comment: Hi gucce, thanks for your response! The `code` .validate("$.requests[0].request.body", @matchesXml('citrus:readFile('classpath:output/esb/add_conf_to_cart/response2.xml')')@) `code` looks promising. I'll give it a try and let you know.

Comment: Note that you can use as many `validate` checks as you want. So you could also validate other parts of the response body.

Comment: Validation now compares the XML part. I’m not sure if it considers the data to be XML though. I’ve used this:

    variable(“jsonXml”, “’citrus:readFile(‘classpath:output/esb/add_conf_to_cart/response2.xml’)’“);

and then

    http()
        .client(wiremockClient)
        .receive()
        .response(HttpStatus.OK)
        .messageType(MessageType.JSON)
        .validate("$.requests[0].request.body", "${jsonXml}")
    ;

I’ve copied expect and actual messages to files and used IntelliJ compare. IntelliJ considers expected and actual to be equal, but Citrus doesn’t.

Comment: You're missing the most important part, the `@matchesXml('')@`. It should read like this: `.validate("$.requests[0].request.body", "@matchesXml('${jsonXml}')")`

Comment: ow, you're right, but shouldn't that be .validate("$.requests[0].request.body", "@matchesXml('${jsonXml}')@")? with a trailing @? If I do that my test case complains that the xml isn't valid. 'Caused by: com.consol.citrus.exceptions.CitrusRuntimeException: org.w3c.dom.ls.LSException: Content is not allowed in prolog.' so it thinks it's handling xml. The source of my message is a bit dodgy so maybe the parser is right.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I forgot the trailing `@`. And yes, it is treated as XML now. `Content is not allowed in prolog` might be some whitespace in front of the XML declaration (`<?xml version="1.0"?>`).

Answer (score 2):

Using gucce's solution I finally found the correct syntax for validating XML. The code now looks like this:

```
        variable("jsonXml", "'citrus:readFile('classpath:output/esb/add_conf_to_cart/response2.xml')'");

        http()
                .client(wiremockClient)
                .send()
                .get("/__admin/requests")
                .accept("application/json");

        HttpClientResponseActionBuilder body = http()
                .client(wiremockClient)
                .receive()
                .response(HttpStatus.OK)
                .messageType(MessageType.JSON)
                .validate("$.requests[0].request.body", "@matchesXml(${jsonXml})@")
                ;
```

The error I made was first in forgetting the second @ and then in adding single quotes around the parameter to matchesXML. So

```
.validate("$.requests[0].request.body", "@matchesXml('${jsonXml}')@")
```

won't work but

```
.validate("$.requests[0].request.body", "@matchesXml(${jsonXml})@")
```

will do the job.

Comment: I'm glad you made it work. I'm also very content with the solution which doesn't need any '\' or `"` escaping. You're right about the single quotes. Somewhere hidden in  the [documentation](http://www.citrusframework.org/reference/2.7.2/html/index.html#functions-concat) it says `Please do not forget to mark static text with single quote signs.`, i.e., non-static text should not be marked with single quotes. This should be made clearer in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

A different solution uses an implementation of AbstractTestAction to call a method that does the validation in the context of Citrus:

```
    http()
            .client(wiremockClient)
            .receive()
            .response(HttpStatus.OK)
            .messageType(MessageType.JSON)
            .extractFromPayload("$.requests[0].request.body", "body")
    ;
    action(action(new DummyAction(new File(EXPECTED_OUTPUT_FILE)));
```

The action() call registers DummyAction to execute a validation. In my case it needs a file to validate the contents of the body that was extracted from the payload by http().extractFromPayload("$.requests[0].request.body", "body")

Class DummyAction looks like this:

```
class DummyAction extends AbstractTestAction {

    private File expectedOutputFile;

    public DummyAction(File expectedOutputFile) {
        this.expectedOutputFile = expectedOutputFile;
    }

    @Override
    public void doExecute(TestContext testContext) {
        String body = testContext.getVariable("body");
        Assert.assertTrue(body.startsWith("<soapenv:Envelope "), "Request should start with '<soapenv:Envelope '");
    }
}
```

doExecute() has access to variables that are available in the context of the test. So extractFromPayload() places a variable named 'body' in the context which is then later accessed in doExecute(). 
This solution allows arbitrary Java code to run, in my case to extract an XML document from a SOAP envelope, buried in a JSON document.